# Digital transmission of composite video

Tags: analog, communication, video, digital-modulation

As the tittle suggests, I was thinking about making a wireless composite video transmission between a small camera (such as those sold for flying FPV) and a receiver. The two main specifications it must have are near-0 latency (the lower the better) and it must work well when the transmission is made at ground level (multipath is a thing to consider.) I would not care about receiving a black and white image or a lower quality video (less bits in the ADC.) The distance between transmitter and receiver will be at most 170m, but I can use almost any type of omnidirectional antenna. I know at first this may seem pretty difficult, but here are the ideas I came with:

The first part of the system is the ADC. Here, as I do not need any sound or color information (only luminance is needed,) we could go fot two different options:

**Idea 1:** It consists of sending the signal as-is, with an ADC with a sampling frequency of nearly 9MHz (composite video's bandwidth is around 5MHz) and 8bit. The bit speed at the output will be 70Mbit/s. *Pros:* The original image is sent, so it has good quality and is easier to work with it. *Cons:* 70Mbit/s is a lot.

**Idea 2:** It consists of a lowpass filter before the ADC, with a cutoff frequency of around 2.5-3MHz (only luminance is sent.) The ADC would the need a sampling frequency between 5-6MHz, and it would also be chosen to code the info with 6bits. The bit speed at the output will be 36Mbit/s. *Pros:* 36Mbit/s is almost half of the 70Mbit/s. *Cons:* I am not sure if the filter would destroy the sync information, and that would be an issue.

Since we must fight multipath, the digital modulation to be used will be FSK. I know that before sending the image, it would be good to wait for the whole frame to be digitalized, saving the output of the ADC to a buffer, and then sending the image as a whole. On the one hand, I am afraid that this would add too much latency to the process and, on the other one, it seems to be too complicated to be implemented in an efficient way. As either the first 70Mbit/s or the latter 36Mbit/s are huge speeds, another two ideas on how to transmit arose:

**Idea 1:** Use hardware that works with an already studied protocol which can handle great speeds (maybe p2p WiFi or WiFi direct.) *Pros:* seems easier to implement and image quality can be great. *Cons:* distributing the data into packages can add a lot of latency to the whole comunications system. Moreover, if data rate is large, it is difficult to achieve 170m of distance.

**Idea 2:** As most of ADCs have one output per bit, and the total throughtput needed for each one would be by far lower than the total, the plan is to use, if the ADC codes the information in n bits, n transmitters at different frequencies simultaneously, that handle the ADC output as a serial input of data. My first idea was using NRF24L01 modules, but they can only trnasmit at 2Mbit/s. I would have to find an alternative. *Pros:* seems easier and faster. *Cons:* larger probability of receiving erroneous bits at the receiver. Besides, I did not find many modules that fit the data rate requirements. If there were a transceiver that did not use package-structured data but some type of serial communicstion based on an input/buzzer it would be perfect.

Will this project work? What would be the best implementation? Do you find doing it in a non-industrial "homemade" way realistic?

*Edit:* I also found this [website](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/composite-video-signal), but I think none of the methods mentioned there are elementary enought to be developed in a homemade project.

Comment: Why digitally?  None of your schemes provides better quality or better performance than transmitting it as an analog signal.

Comment: @JRE I already have an analog communication system and even at small range you always find some small noise or interferences. I know that maybe better filters would help, but I also thought about this as an excuse to dig into digital communications

Comment: None of the ideas you've come up with would make use of any of the advantages of digital transmission.  You should expect worse performance rather than better.

Comment: @JRE Why would that be?

Comment: The advantage of digital transmission  is that you can add checksums to the data to detect and recover from bit errors.  Bit errors **will** happen - your analog signal shows corruption, so your digital transmission will be corrupted as well.  But, you have nothing to correct the errors.  What happens when the most significant bit has an error?  It is as likely to happen to it as to the a lower value bit.

Comment: @JRE but digital transmission can handle small errors in the received signal if they are tiny enought as for not changing the decission, while in analog any error can be corrected

Comment: @user3141592 But with an analog signal, _occasional errors don't matter_. They'll show up as minor imperfections in the image, which the viewer can ignore.

Comment: @JRE But, if I wanted to achieve perfect images, would it be necessary to add the redundancy bits you talk about? If so, as that would sacrify latency, isn't it even possible to design low-latency a transmission system which (besides certain error probability) achieves perfect frames?

Comment: You are forgetting about how much distortion you get with your LPF image rejection and group delay that’s why it would look worse

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy would distorsion be an issue if the cutoff frequency is chosen so that it just rejects chrominance? I read around the internet that luminance BW is just about 3MHz. And, about group delay, would that really create distorsion? I did not take it into account. Then, I would go for my idea 1 there

Comment: If you only sample 2x the bandwidth at -3dB you most certainly will get massive ghosting from group delay and distortion from aliasing. Try  5x the -3dB BW or 2x the -43dB BW !

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy thanks! I did not know that results. However, having that into account, the data rate needes to transmit video is massive, isn't it?

Comment: Yes uncompressed is massive, that’s why they compress it >10:1 and more

Comment: *Isn't it even possible to design low-latency a transmission system which (besides certain error probability) achieves perfect frames?*  That pretty much sums up the question that information theory answers.  The answer is -- not without huge power and bandwidth increases.

Answer (score 2):

There are commercial chips that will digitize an NTSC (or PAL) signal for you a 8 to 10 bits of precision, but they typically do it at the standard rate of 27 MHz, giving a raw bit rate of 216 - 270 Mbps.

But after you have this digital signal, it is relatively straightforward to throw away the parts you don't care about (the chroma channels, the audio, etc.) and decimate the sample rate. You can even compress the data using an [H.26x encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) to get the data rate down to 1 Mbps or less.

There are SoC chips with hardware video support that can do this sort of thing, or you could look into using an FPGA.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Wouldn't compression/decompression add a lot of latency to the system?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "a lot". The added latency should be 1 frame or less.